# Is it possible to have a list of objects with different generics/types as parameters

Tags: c#, generics

consider the following Code:

```
class Collision<type1, type2> 
{
    // further Code
}
```

is it possible to have a (for instance) `LinkedList<>` which has a generic `Collision` as its Paramater? In other words: can I somehow implement a `LinkedList<>` which accepts Collision objects will all kinds of parameters?

```
public LinkedList< Collision<Unit, Unit> > collisionList = new LinkedList< Collision<Unit,Unit> >();
```

With this approach I used the base class `Unit` as a replacement for the two child classes `Player` and `Enemy`. But I also have a class `Environment` which isn't a child class but shall also be a possible Parameter for `Collision`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you want something like `class MyClass : LinkedList<Collision<T, T>>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An approach is to use an interface:

```
interface ICollision
{
    object PropertyOfType1{get;}
    object PropertyOfType2{get;}
}
```

and then a generic class that inherits from that interface:

```
class Collision<type1,type2>:ICollision
{
    public type1 PropertyOfType1 {get;set;}
    public type2 PropertyOfType2 {get;set;}

    object ICollision.PropertyOfType1
    {
        get{return PropertyOfType1;}
    }

    object ICollision.PropertyOfType2
    {
        get{return PropertyOfType2;}
    }
}
```

then you can create your linked list using the interface:

```
LinkedList<ICollision> collisionList  = new LinkedList<ICollision>();

collisionList.AddLast(new Collision<int,int>());
collisionList.AddLast(new Collision<double,double>());
```

Comment: Similar to the answer I was about to post, but not exactly the same.  Good answer.

Comment: This is the way to go and better then my `object` suggestion IMO.

Answer (score 2):

The `Collection<T, K>` can only take obejcts of `T`, `K` or its children. If `Unit` and `Environment` are in no direct relation you could use `object`:

```
Collision<object, object>
```

For the "or its children" to work you ned to use "[covaraince](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)":

```
interface ICollision<out T, out K> { }
class Collision<T, K> : ICollision<T, K> { }
```

and then make a list like:

```
var collisionList = new LinkedList<ICollision<Unit, Unit>>();
```

You need the interface as classes do not support covariance, but then you can add e.g. `Collision<Player, Enemy>` to the list.

Comment: *can only take obejcts of T, K or its children.* ? Are you sure?

Comment: -1 Classes doesn't support covariance!, Downvote will be removed if you edit the misleading part

Comment: If I understand that correctly, there is no other option than casting the parameter types first to a upper class and then casting it back to the _actual_ type when I want to use it later on?

Comment: @user3293330: Yes, but no cast is needed "to the upper class". But see Albertos answer, as this is a better approach then using `object`.